# Why I am getting whole path, I want only recently created directory name instead of whole path?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I wrote a script to monitor a particular directory using inotify. If any new directory got created. I want to replace it with that newly created directory name in 'z.sh' file. But I am getting the whole path instead of directory name while using the below script.

```
#!/bin/sh
MONITORDIR1="/var/lib/clickhouse/data/"
monitor() {
inotifywait -m -r -q  $MONITORDIR1 | while read NEWFILE
do
echo "NEW FOLDER CREATED"
cp /home/boctrainee/clickhousescriptold.sql /home/boctrainee/clickhousescript.sql
echo "${NEWFILE#*/*/*/*/*/}"
sed -i -e "s+NEWFILE#*/*/*/*/*/+$NEWTENANTNAME+g" /home/boctrainee/clickhousescript.sql
done
}
monitor $MONITORDIR1 &
```

Please give your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know in which directory the file `$NEWFILE` (given with the full path) lives, just issue:

```
directory=$(dirname "$NEWFILE")
```